# Python: asking user for input with prior input in the prompt?

Tags: python, input, user-input

I'm using Python, and I want to ask a user for input to define a variable, then ask for another input using what they inputted into the first question as part of the second question.

That might be confusing.  I mean like this:

```
hometeam = str(input("Home team?"))
ppg = input(hometeam "Average Points per Game?")
print(ppg)
```

For example, if the user inputs "Cowboys" for hometeam, I'd like the program to ask "Cowboys Average Points per Game?" for the second question.

I'm getting a syntax error with a carrot pointing at the last quotation mark.

Comment: The duplicate should provide more than enough examples how to properly interpolate strings in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You saved that input into the variable "hometeam", so you can do something like this using "+":

`ppg = input(hometeam + " Average Points per Game?")`

Answer (score 0):

```
hometeam = str(input("Home team?"))
ppg = input("{0} Average Points per Game?".format(hometeam))
print(ppg)
```

Comment: You probably want to have a whitespace: `" Average Points per Game?"`

Comment: Thanks, updated answer.